# SQL Server : bit column's default value is not applied?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has boolean columns with `NOT NULL` and with default values `0`.

However I'm getting an 515 error on insert query without specifying those columns.

> General error: 515 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the
>   SQL Server [515] (severity 16) [(null)]
>
> (SQL: insert into [some_table]
>   ([uid], [gmt_offset], [locale], [updated_at], [created_at]) values
>   (122, 7200, en_US, 2016-01-15 18:42:57.000, 2016-01-15 18:42:57.000))'

[image]

Comment: could you post the `insert` statement?

Comment: And `create table` statement

Comment: are those dates properly quoted in the actual query? because as-is there, they're invalid dates, actually seen as mathematical subtraction operations.

Comment: Error 515 details are "cannot insert the value NULL into column"

Comment: are you sure you are inserting values into *all* the `not null` columns?

Comment: Your value for `Default Value or Binding` property should be `((0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code, but looking up 515, [it says](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258724%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> Error 515
> SQL Server 2000
> Error 515
> Severity Level 16
>
> Message Text
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column '%.*ls', table '%.*ls'; column does not allow nulls. %ls fails.
>
> Explanation
> This error occurs at run time when an attempt is made to use a null value while inserting or updating a column that does not allow null values.

Are you sure you are not specifying a NULL?

Comment: Ah, sorry guys – there was two fields that I had forgotten to specify default values for...! It was a big table =/